# squid proxy slow response

Tags: linux, networking, proxy, iptables

We are using the squid proxy in our setup and implemented as transparent proxy with user authentication.
Before couple of days, while we are trying to setup the iptables the squid started performing very slowly. The searches and responses became 80% slow comparing before iptables.
So we just stopped iptables. After shutting down the iptables, we got the normal working of proxy and response is good for requested pages.

Any Suggestions to fix the slow response problem?.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use transparent proxy with proxy user authentication.

http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/InterceptionProxy#Why_can.27t_I_use_authentication_together_with_interception_proxying.3F

Your authentication rules won't work with intercepted connections.

Comment: I'm using the setup as interception proxy = squid proxy and user authentication = squid user authentication(using the proxy_auth) and content filtering = dansguardian, you were explaining about the authentication rules and currently my question was about the slow performance.